# as old as my father

Tags: comparison

a. I don't know anyone who was as old as my father when he retired.

b. I don't know anyone who was as old as my father when they retired.

Could one use these sentences to say

1. I don't know anyone who retired at a a higher age than my father.

?

(b) could mean:

I don't know anyone who was as old as my father is now when they retired.

(a) could mean:

I don't know anyone who was the same age as my father when he retired.
(a somewhat strange thing to say)

But could either mean (1)?

Comment: I think both sentences would be understood to mean (1), although they don't express the meaning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences literally mean, "*I don't know anyone who retired at an age as high (or higher) than **my father's age now***".

However, since it's unnatural to compare one person's retirement age with another person's age, it will be understood to mean (1) without special explanation in the context.

Your sentence (1) is a natural way to express it. The others are not.